# Where to set the size of a view controller presented in a popover?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios6, uipopovercontroller

Based on Apple's  [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html), my app is presenting a view controller in a popover, which is trigged by a bar button:

```
- (IBAction)configChartTapped:(id)sender {

GrowthChartConfigOneViewController *panelViewController = [[GrowthChartConfigOneViewController alloc]init];

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:panelViewController];
popover.delegate = self;

// Store the popover in a custom property for later use.
self.popover = popover;

[self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; 
}
```

However, I did not find a way to set the size of the popover.

**Question: Where and how should I set the size of the popover and its view controller? Can I set the size directly in XCode to have the view correctly sized in storyboard?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give popovercontentsize and make sure that view should fit in popover size as defined below:

```
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: panelViewController];
    popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(550, 700);
```

Comment: Can I set the popover size directly in Xcode? When I set the size in code, the popover view has the standard view size and is not correctly sized in storyboard.

Answer (score 5):

You can also set it within the popover class itself. This way if you allow the popover to be called from multiple places, you can just set the size once.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 216.0);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Alex, you'd likely have to move that to viewDidLoad.

Comment: In iOS7 Xcode says contentSizeForViewInPopover is deprecated and to use "preferredContentSize" instead, like this: self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(630, 340);

Answer (score 2):

Good answer above but I just wanted to update it for storyboard due to my slightly different needs. If you're instantiating using storyboard identifier like this:

```
CBItemViewController *addNewPayee = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cbItemPopover"];
```

then you can set the custom size inside the popover's code like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]) {
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(630, 340);
    }
    return self;

}
```