# iPad: Content view is not resized to fit popover

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, resize, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

I'm having some trouble with presenting a content view in a popover. I'm using the following code to set up the popover with a view controller which I instantiate from the storyboard. The view controller in which I'm presenting the popover is within a navigation controller :

```
    MyViewController *viewController =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
    viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(382, 502);
    UIPopoverController *popover =  [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:viewController];

    self.popoverController = popover; //self.popoverController is a private property of type UIPopoverController
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Here comes the problem: When I tap the left bar button the popover shows in the correct size with the correct content, but the content view is not resized to the size of the popover. Only the snippet of the content view which is "covered by the popover" is visible.

I'm having the same procedure with a table view, which is working perfectly-the table is fitted to the popover. I also tried to set the size of the popover controller itself, like it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864709/where-to-set-the-size-of-a-view-controller-presented-in-a-popover). And I tried out some settings with the springs and struts of the affected view controller. But the outcome is always the same.

Now I really run out of ideas what I could try out, or what I'm possibly doing wrong/missing...HELP :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TableView adjusts itself to the size of the container view controller it is put in. 
That is a feature of a UITableViewController. 
When you present the TableView by UIPopoverController, the popover determines the size for the table.

This mechanism does not work for all views, so you need to set the size of your view itself as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes solutions are so close :) I finally got it to work with your tip and the instructions from  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161909/how-to-use-storyboard-to-make-popover-that-can-be-used-in-code) I also tried it by hooking up the view controller's view via IBOutlet and setting the size programmatically after instantiating it, but that didn't work at all. Can you point me to a way to accomplish resizing the view controller's view in code and not in Interface Builder?

Comment: You're very welcome! I was stuck in the same way a week ago. Resizing _should_ work if you let your own ViewController resize the view. Plus you may want to give it a `[ viewController setNeedsDisplay ];` to trigger the process. (Please accept the answer to enhance my rep)

Answer (score 0):

There were some changes between iOS 6 and iOS 7 that mean views don't always resize as expected. A number of different methods and techniques can be used to provide the desired behaviour. These include providing guidance via the autoresizing mask:

```
// Resizing behaviour
self.view.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth+UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

And sometimes the parent view needs to be told to resize subviews as well.

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
```

In addition Matt Neuberg (Programming iOS 7) tells us how to prevent content being hidden underneath the navigation bars (and toolbar), using the following:

```
// Stops the view going underneath the navigation bars 
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Then there is the:

```
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
```

method used for redrawing. The first step is learning that all these weird and wonderful methods exist and the second is to find out the most economical implementation to get them all working for you.